# Connecting Kafka Producer to Kafka broker in Docker container through Java libraries

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I want to make a Kafka producer send messages to a topic in a Kafka cluster through org.apache.kafka Java library. Here's what I've done:

I started a Kafka and a Zookeeper server using `docker-compose up -d` with this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    # build: .
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.99.100
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "testTopic:1:1"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Result:

```
          Name                         Command               State                         Ports
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dockertoolbox_kafka_1       start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:32768->9092/tcp
dockertoolbox_zookeeper_1   /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/sshd  ...   Up      0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

Then, I took the code from https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-kafka/producer-example-in-apache-kafka/ and changed the port number:

```
public class SampleProducer extends Thread {
    private final KafkaProducer<Integer, String> producer;
    private final String topic;
    private final Boolean isAsync;

    public static final String KAFKA_SERVER_URL = "localhost";
    public static final int KAFKA_SERVER_PORT = 32768;
    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "SampleProducer";

    public SampleProducer(String topic, Boolean isAsync) {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_SERVER_URL + ":" + KAFKA_SERVER_PORT);
        properties.put("client.id", CLIENT_ID);
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
        this.topic = topic;
        this.isAsync = isAsync;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int messageNo = 1;
        while (true) {
            final String messageStr = "Message_" + messageNo;
            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (isAsync) { // Send asynchronously
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
                        messageNo,
                        messageStr), new DemoCallBack(startTime, messageNo, messageStr));
            } else { // Send synchronously
                try {
                    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
                            messageNo,
                            messageStr)).get();
                    System.out.println("Sent message: (" + messageNo + ", " + messageStr + ")");
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // handle the exception
                }
            }
            ++messageNo;
        }
    }
}

class DemoCallBack implements Callback {

    private final long startTime;
    private final int key;
    private final String message;

    public DemoCallBack(long startTime, int key, String message) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.key = key;
        this.message = message;
    }

    /**
     * onCompletion method will be called when the record sent to the Kafka Server has been acknowledged.
     *
     * @param metadata  The metadata contains the partition and offset of the record. Null if an error occurred.
     * @param exception The exception thrown during processing of this record. Null if no error occurred.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
        final long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        if (metadata != null) {
            System.out.println(
                    "message(" + key + ", " + message + ") sent to partition(" + metadata.partition() +
                    "), " +
                    "offset(" + metadata.offset() + ") in " + elapsedTime + " ms");
        } else {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class KafkaProducerDemo {
    public static final String TOPIC = "testTopic";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final boolean isAsync = false;
        final SampleProducer producerThread = new SampleProducer(TOPIC, isAsync);
        // start the producer
        producerThread.start();

    }
}
```

But when I run KafkaProducerDemo, it continues to print:

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | SampleProducer] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=SampleProducer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:32768) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

What should I change?